# CORS origin error spring boot + angular on localhost

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, cors

I'm trying to consume a Restful api developed on spring boot via an Angular app and I faced this issue here is below my implementation :

1. Spring boot controller :

```js
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200/")
public class ProductController {
    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public void addProduct(@RequestBody Product p){
        productService.addProduct(p);
    }

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public List<Product> getListOfProducts(){
        return productService.getAllProducts();
    }
}
```

2. Angular Service

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getProducts(){
    return this.http.get("localhost:4200/api/list");
  }
}
```

3. Angular Component

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductsService } from '../products.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products.component.css']
})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private products:ProductsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.products.getProducts().subscribe((res)=>{
      console.warn(res);
    })
  }

}
```

When trying to run the angular app i face this error :

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:4200/api/list' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GisVe.png)

Comment: `this.http.get("localhost:4200/api/list")`? Shouldn't this being using the full URL for the service you are trying to call?

Comment: As previous commenter says, you need to add http:// to the front of your URL: as the error tells you, it doesn't know which protocol you're trying to use.

Comment: In addition to the comments above:`http://localhost:4200/` is not  an _origin_. Drop the trailing slash in `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200/")`.

Answer (score -1):

Alternative answer. You can add to config class:

```
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("HEAD", "OPTIONS", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .maxAge(3600);
    }
}
```